# SQL SELECT Sort by specific row

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table `food`, which I query `SELECT name FROM food ORDER BY name`:

```
| name
|--------
| Apple
| Banana
| Carrot
| Donut
...
```

I wish to specify that *specific* items of my choice be pinned to the top (e.g. "Lemon" and then "Carrot"), *if* they are in the table. Like so:

```
| name
| -------
| Lemon
| Carrot
| Apple
| Banana
| Donut
...
```

What kind of SQL query can I use to get this specific sort?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a case statement in your order by clause to prioritize items with a certain name.

The following will put Lemon and Carrot in priority order by assigning them the values of 1 and 2 from the case, where all others will get the value 3.  Those remaining that were assigned 3 will then be sorted by the second expression in the order by clause, which is just the name column.

```
SELECT *
FROM food
ORDER BY
  CASE name
    WHEN 'Lemon' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Carrot' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END,
  name
```

Comment: He already added `name` to the `order by` clause, so it's good.

Comment: this was also the only answer which was not RDBMS specific @cameraguy258

Comment: How Can I pin 'Lemon' and 'Carrot' in the last and second last row instead of 1st and 2nd row?

Comment: @RaviKumar - just reverse the values of the case - 'Lemon' = 3, 'Carrot' = 2, default = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Make a look up table like this:

```
WITH odering(F, Ord) AS
(
   VALUES ('Lemmon', 2),
          ('Carrot', 1)
)
SELECT name
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN ordering Ord on T.name = Ord.name
ORDER BY COALESCE(Ord.Ord, 0) DESC, Name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, this is going to be RDBMS specific. The one being used is not specified.

MySQL, commonly used, provides a function field().  Good for custom sorts on bounded values.

```
mysql> create temporary table food as select 'Apple' as food union select 'Banana' union select 'Carrot'  union select 'Donut';
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from food;
+--------+
| food   |
+--------+
| Apple  |
| Banana |
| Carrot |
| Donut  |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from food order by field (food, 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Donut');
+--------+
| food   |
+--------+
| Carrot |
| Apple  |
| Banana |
| Donut  |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use CTE and go like this:

```
WITH FoodOrder(name, foodOrder)
AS
(
    SELECT name
            , foodOrder = CASE name
                            WHEN 'Lemon' THEN 200
                            WHEN 'Carrot' THEN 100
                            ELSE 0
                        END                      
    FROM food   
)
SELECT name
FROM FoodOrder
ORDER BY foodOrder DESC, name
```

Please note that if you will choose enough spacing between CASE values (0, 100 ,200) you can easily add another prioritized food afterwards if needed without overwriting already existing values.